# Looking for Specific Date

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Anyone know how to query for a specific date within entity framework ? I tried following code, but it gives me NotSupportedException.

```
var deposit = (from tempDeposit in entities.Deposit
where !tempDeposit.IsApproved
&& tempDeposit.CreatedDate.Date == DateTime.Today
select tempDeposit).FirstOrDefault();
```

I also tried following code but still gave me NotSupportedException.

```
var deposit = (from tempDeposit in entities.Deposit
where !tempDeposit.IsApproved
&& tempDeposit.CreatedDate.ToFullString() == DateTime.Today.ToFullString()
select tempDeposit).FirstOrDefault();
```

ToFullString() is an extension method

```
public static string ToFullString(this DateTime date){
  return date.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
var d1 = DateTime.Today;
var d2 = d1.AddDays(1);
var deposit = (from tempDeposit in entities.Deposit
               where !tempDeposit.IsApproved
                     && tempDeposit.CreatedDate >= d1
                     && tempDeposit.CreatedDate < d2
               select tempDeposit).FirstOrDefault();
```

Since you can't use the .Date property of a DateTime column, since that would have to be written in SQL with a range of converts, casts, truncates, etc. then you need to compare the whole DateTime value, date and time both, to a value, and thus you need to compare to a range.

**Edit** Changed to reflect that .AddDays isn't supported.

Comment: It still gives me this, System.NotSupportedException: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime AddDays(Double)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: Ok, then I should've written the query the way I usually do it :P though I will confess to not using LINQ-To-SQL much yet, only for experimentation.

Comment: No problem m8, I've found the solution based on your answer

Answer (score 2):

Well, after sometime tried, I found the solution

```
var deposit = entities1.Deposit
              .Where("CreatedDate >= @0 and CreatedDate < @1", DateTime.Today, DateTime.Today.AddDays(1))
              .FirstOrDefault();
```